# Storage statistics of a folder in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I would like the stats of specific folders in Azure Blob Storage. For example I would like to know how many files are present in a folder, whats the size of each file or whats the total size of a folder. Does blob storage provide similar data through an api endpoint?

**Edit:** I have a very large number of files on Azure Blob so I am looking for a solution where I do not have to iterate over all the files in order to calculate total size of the virtual folder.

Answer (score 1):

> Does blob storage provide similar data through an api endpoint?

As such Azure Blob Storage does not provide an API to get storage statistics at the folder level but you can make use of [`List Blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) REST API operation to get that information.

List Blobs operation will list the blobs insider a container but you can use `prefix` parameter to get the list of blobs inside a virtual folder where `prefix` will be the path of the virtual folder. For example, if you wish to list the blobs inside `folder1` virtual folder, you would specify `prefix` as `folder1/`

Each item in the list is a blob which will have a `size` attribute which will give you the size of the blob. You will simply add the size of individual blobs to get the total size of the folder.

Comment: Isnt there a faster way of doing it? For example if I just want the total size of virtual folder, isnt there like a property for that?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no property for that. You will need to iterate through all the blobs and add up their sizes to get the folder size.